# How to find median given frequency of numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The `Numbers` table keeps the value of number and its frequency.

```
+----------+-------------+
|  Number  |  Frequency  |
+----------+-------------|
|  0       |  7          |
|  1       |  1          |
|  2       |  3          |
|  3       |  1          |
+----------+-------------+
```

In this table, the numbers are 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, so the median is (0 + 0) / 2 = 0. How to find median (output shown) given frequency of numbers?

```
+--------+
| median |
+--------|
| 0.0000 |
+--------+
```

I found the following solution [here](https://github.com/kamyu104/LeetCode/blob/master/MySQL/find-median-given-frequency-of-numbers.sql). However, I am unable to understand it. Can someone please explain the solution and/or post a different solution with explanation?

```
SELECT AVG(n.Number) AS median 
FROM Numbers n LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT Number, @prev := @count AS prevNumber, (@count := @count + Frequency) AS countNumber
FROM Numbers, 
(SELECT @count := 0, @prev := 0, @total := (SELECT SUM(Frequency) FROM Numbers)) temp ORDER BY Number
) n2
ON n.Number = n2.Number
WHERE 
(prevNumber < floor((@total+1)/2) AND countNumber >= floor((@total+1)/2))
OR
(prevNumber < floor((@total+2)/2) AND countNumber >= floor((@total+2)/2))
```

Here's the SQL script for reproducibility:

```
CREATE TABLE `Numbers` (
  `Number` INT NULL,
  `Frequency` INT NULL);

INSERT INTO `Numbers` (`Number`, `Frequency`) VALUES ('0', '7');
INSERT INTO `Numbers` (`Number`, `Frequency`) VALUES ('1', '1');
INSERT INTO `Numbers` (`Number`, `Frequency`) VALUES ('2', '3');
INSERT INTO `Numbers` (`Number`, `Frequency`) VALUES ('3', '1');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative sum and then take the midway point.  I think the logic looks like this:

```
select avg(number)
from (select t.*, (@rf := @rf + frequency) as running_frequency
      from (select t.* from t order by number) t cross join
           (select @rf := 0) params
     ) t
where running_frequency - frequency >= ceil(@rf / 2) and
      running_frequency <= ceil((@rf + 1) / 2);
```

Comment: This returns `NULL`. Also, I know that cumulative sum should be used for this problem but if possible, can you add a little more explanation?

Comment: @ChaityaShah . . . It is all in the conditions in the `where` clause.  Try it now.